# What is the message of the song Aoi Shiori?

Tags: song-lyrics

What are the more subtle messages held in [Aoi Shiori](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/anohana/aoishiori.htm)? I think the English translation lacks a bit of the deeper undertones of the Japanese song. Please answer the following questions:

1. What is the meaning of this?

   > どれか一つをえらべば　音をたてて壊れる
   >
   > If you choose any one, it will break with a sound - 
   >   That is what love is, I joked, and you laughed.
2. Is it known what "the two of you" refers to? In the Japanese lyrics, is it known if "the two of you" refers to the "narrator" and the person he's singing about? Or is it the person he's singing about and someone else?

I'm trying to learn some vocabulary from songs and answers would be awesome. If there's any other subtext that I'm missing please don't hesitate to add it onto your answer.

Comment: どれか一つをえらべば　音をたてて壊れる --- That's pretty good. The girl gave a cryptic definition of love, and the guy is always going to remember it all his life.  _________________ In an old movie, the guy says "I"m sorry." and the girl says:  "Love means never having to say you're sorry".

Comment: Re:  "the two of you" -- そうやって今は僕の方へ　押しつける陽射しの束 / まだ二人はすぐそこにいるのに　「どうかまた会えますように」なんて どうかしてるみたい _________________________ It must mean "two of us" ; I don't see a 3rd person anywhere __________________I wish you 'all would study (learn from) more classic songs.... Aoi Shiori (i think) indirectly alludes to this classic song: さみしさのつれづれに手紙をしたためています あなたに黒いインクがきれいでしょう 青い便せんが悲しいでしょう .... ____________ Note: 青い便せん (& 青い栞」（あおいしおり）)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original Japanese lyrics are pretty vague, and they are full of puzzling and suggestive expressions. That said, apparently this song is about an indescribable anxiety of the boy (= 僕 = "I"), who probably is in love with each other (with 君 = "you") for now, but is worried because their current relationship is fragile for some reason. Even though they're happy today, he can't help worrying about the future, and that's why he keeps saying どうかしてるみたい ("There must be something wrong with me.")

The fantranslation in the link is pretty good overall, but seemingly there are a few flaws.

> どれか一つをえらべば　音をたてて壊れる
>   "If you choose any one, it will break with a sound.
>   それが愛だなんて　おどけて君は笑ってた
>   That is love." — (saying so,) you were playfully laughing.

I think it is not 僕 ("I") but 君 ("you") who were joking here. The girl is (jokingly) saying  something like "If you decide to gain someone's love, it can never be achieved". Taking the context into consideration, I feel this implies something along the lines of "You can never control someone's mind, so take it easy, what happens happens." She doesn't seem to be as worried as the boy.

Regarding your second question, I think there are only two people in this song, which are 僕 (= "I") and 君 (= "you"). So this 二人 (lit. "two people") should have been translated as "the two of *us*."

Comment: Thanks Uzumaki-san. If I ask a similar question about a different song in the future, I hope you'll be just as helpful.